# Not working autocomplete when not/prefilled form inputs by values from other component

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I have used service for forwarding values from first to second component.
In case I fill form in first component (url: localhost:4200) and then submit, it is redirecting me to url: localhost:4200/results where is another component.
Everything works properly and I get right values from first form as a prefilled values (using ngModel). But in case I go to localhost:4200/results directly and want fill that form, autocomplete does not work and cosole throws error messages: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined"

I have tried change status of parametres object from undefined a define its properities this way

```
parameters = {
  location: '',
  type: '',
  pricefrom: '',
  priceto: '',
};
```

But it didn't work anyways and had same issue. Only thing which worked was deleting  `[(ngModel)]="parameters.xxxxx"` in every single input, but obviously it did not give me prefilled values.

```
     <form [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

      <input type="text"  class="form-control" matInput placeholder="Okres" [matAutocomplete]="auto" formControlName="location" name="location" [(ngModel)]="parameters.location">      

      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
          {{option}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>

       <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Try creating a sample on Stackblitz

Comment: And share some more relevant code related to the data passing , redirection etc

Comment: Hello @YashKrishan, Ive got it. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Ive got it. Resolved by condition in second's component

```
ngOnInit(){    if(this.parameters){
      this.parameters = this.searchedParameters.getParameters()
      }
      else{this.parameters = {location: '', pricefrom: '', priceto: '', type: ''};
      }
```